# QToolButton to show menu after pressing Alt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a tool button with an associated menu.

```
m_mainMenuButton = new ToolButton("menu.png", tr("Open menu"));
m_mainMenuButton->setMenu(m_mainMenu);
m_mainMenuButton->setPopupMode(QToolButton::InstantPopup);
```

I want this menu to be shown when the user presses and releases Alt. This way the normal `QMenuBar` gets activated on Windows (and I want to have this tool button instead of `QMenuBar`). I tried this:

```
m_mainMenuButton->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Alt));
```

but it does not show the menu when Alt is pressed and released. Or this:

```
auto shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Alt), this);
connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, m_mainMenuButton, &QToolButton::showMenu);
```

which does not do anything too. I tried to override key press and release events but then I found it interferes with other key shortcuts which are using key Alt as a modifier, e.g "Alt+Left".

Any ideas how to do this?

UPDATE a minimal example which shows that Alt does not work as a shortcut.

```
#include <QAction>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QShortcut>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow w;

    auto label = new QLabel();

    auto menu = new QMenu(&w);
    // intentionally added a shortcut which contains Alt as modifier to test it does not interfere with the menu
    menu->addAction("Action", [label]{ label->setText("Trigered!"); }, QKeySequence("Alt+Left"));

    auto btn = new QToolButton();
    btn->setMenu(menu);
    btn->setPopupMode(QToolButton::InstantPopup);

    // the following lines do not have any effect, the menu is not shown when Alt is pressed and released
    auto shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Alt), &w);
    QObject::connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, btn, &QToolButton::showMenu);

    auto container = new QWidget();
    auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(container);
    layout->addWidget(btn);
    layout->addWidget(label);
    w.setCentralWidget(container);
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: what is `this`?

Comment: `this` is in my case the main window, which is set as the parent of the shortcut. It does not matter, it could be the button as well.

Comment: please, provide a [mcve] ;)

Comment: @eyllanesc  I updated the question and added an example.

Comment: I am suspecting that ALT being a modifier is not a valid shorcut, as I have tried so far the valid shorcuts are MODIFIER + KEY or just KEY.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is for a reason... Shortcuts react to key press event. While Alt shortcut would need to react to key release event (when there was no other key pressed meantime). I am trying to make a workaround...

Comment: Here's how Qt implements it: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qmenubar.cpp?h=5.9#n1495 So it uses an event filter to detect the Alt-Release, but shortcut override for Alt-Press and other shortcuts. Maybe you can build your own thing based on that

Comment: the solution is simple, use an eventFilter that emits some signal and that signal connects to showMenu()

Comment: @king_nak Thanks a lot, this seems to be what I was looking for. If you make it an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version inspired by Qt's implementation in [QMenuBar](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qmenubar.cpp?h=5.9#n1495):

```
class AltButton : public QToolButton {
public:
    AltButton(QWidget *parent) : QToolButton(parent)
    {
        // To handle initial ALT-press in parent
        parent->installEventFilter(this);
        // If reparenting should be possible, override changeEvent
        // You can also make an app-wide event filter if the button should catch all alt presses
    }


protected:
    bool altPressed = false;
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
    {
        if (altPressed) {
            // Alt-press registered before, check alt-Release
            switch (event->type())
            {
            case QEvent::KeyPress:
            case QEvent::KeyRelease:
            {
                QKeyEvent *kev = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
                if (kev->key() == Qt::Key_Alt || kev->key() == Qt::Key_Meta) {
                    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
                        break; // Alt-Press handled below by shortcut override
                    // Alt-Release. Toggle button
                    this->showMenu();
                }
            }
            // fallthrough
            case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
            case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
            case QEvent::MouseMove:
            case QEvent::FocusIn:
            case QEvent::FocusOut:
            case QEvent::ActivationChange:
            case QEvent::Shortcut:
                // These events cancel a alt-trigger
                altPressed = false;
                // Stop listening for global alt-releas
                qApp->removeEventFilter(this);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        } else if (isVisible()) {
            if (event->type() == QEvent::ShortcutOverride) {
                QKeyEvent *kev = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
                if ((kev->key() == Qt::Key_Alt || kev->key() == Qt::Key_Meta) && kev->modifiers() == Qt::AltModifier) {
                    // Alt-Press. Listen globally for alt-release
                    altPressed = true;
                    qApp->installEventFilter(this);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char**argv) {
    QApplication a(argc,argv);

        QMainWindow w;

        auto label = new QLabel();

        auto menu = new QMenu(&w);
        // intentionally added a shortcut which contains Alt as modifier to test it does not interfere with the menu
        menu->addAction("Action", [label]{ label->setText("Trigered!"); }, QKeySequence("Alt+Left"));

        auto btn = new AltButton(&w);
        btn->setMenu(menu);
        btn->setPopupMode(QToolButton::InstantPopup);

        // the following lines do not have any effect, the menu is not shown when Alt is pressed and released
        //auto shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Alt), &w);
        //QObject::connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, btn, &QToolButton::showMenu);

        auto container = new QWidget();
        auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(container);
        layout->addWidget(btn);
        layout->addWidget(label);
        w.setCentralWidget(container);
        w.show();

        return a.exec();
}
```

The Alt-Left shortcut works as expected, and the buttons menu is toggled by a Alt-Pres-Release.

Comment: Works well. I only need to find out how to install the event filter for the top level window. `changeEvent()` does not always work because this button can be a child of widget X which can be reparented to Y which can be then reparented to top level window Z. And if I want to install the event filter for Z, then the button's `changeEvent()` will not be triggered when Y gets reparented to Z. Maybe I am doing something wrong... Anyway, I can call `installFilter()` manually from the top level window and it works.

Comment: In the linked QMenuBar implementation, I saw something about a grand-parent change (I think in the event-filter). Maybe you can use this approach for your case, too.

Comment: Finally I ended up with passing the scope widget (the widget in which Tab key is handled by this menu button) in the constructor. Works very well so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use QObject::installEventFilter
(QObject::eventFilter(obj, event)).

For example

QtStackOverflow.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include <QToolButton>
#include "ui_QtStackOverflow.h"

class QtStackOverflow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtStackOverflow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::QtStackOverflowClass ui;
};

class KeyPressEater : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:
   KeyPressEater(QToolButton*btn) : keyOtherPush(false), keyAltPush(false) { _btn = btn; }

protected:
   bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);

private:
   QToolButton * _btn;
   bool keyOtherPush;
   bool keyAltPush;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "QtStackOverflow.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>

#include <QObject>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QShortcut>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   QMainWindow w;

   auto label = new QLabel();

   auto menu = new QMenu(&w);
   // intentionally added a shortcut which contains Alt as modifier to test it does not interfere with the menu
   int number = 0;
   menu->addAction("Action", [label, &number] {
      label->setText(QString("%1 %2 ").arg("Trigered!").arg(number));
      number++;
   }, QKeySequence("Alt+Left"));

   auto btn = new QToolButton();
   btn->setMenu(menu);
   btn->setPopupMode(QToolButton::InstantPopup);

   // the following lines do not have any effect, the menu is not shown when Alt is pressed and released
   auto shortcut = new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Alt), &w);
   QObject::connect(shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, btn, &QToolButton::showMenu);

   KeyPressEater *m_keyPressEater;
   m_keyPressEater = new KeyPressEater(btn);
   qApp->installEventFilter(m_keyPressEater);

   auto container = new QWidget();
   auto layout = new QVBoxLayout(container);
   layout->addWidget(btn);
   layout->addWidget(label);
   w.setCentralWidget(container);
   w.show();

   return a.exec();
}

bool KeyPressEater::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
   if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
   {
      int key = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event)->key();

      if (key == Qt::Key_Alt)
      {
         keyAltPush = true;
      }
      else {
         keyOtherPush = true;
      }

      return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
   }
   else if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyRelease)
   {
      int key = static_cast<QKeyEvent *>(event)->key();

      if (key == Qt::Key_Alt) {
         if (keyAltPush == true && keyOtherPush == false) {
            _btn->showMenu();
         }
      }
      else {
         keyAltPush = false;
         keyOtherPush = false;
      }
      return true;
   }
   else {
      return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
   }
}
```

In this case you will get all key press at any time.

Then you need check QObject *senderObj = sender()

Comment: But this would trigger even if I press, for example, "Alt+Left", which is a valid shortcut for another action. The problem with shortcut is that you first press "Alt" (which is when the menu would be opened - and I do not want this) and then "Left".

Comment: I've corrected my code.  You need check QObject *senderObj = sender()  -  who send key "Alt+Left"

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. My problem is not to trigger "Alt+Left", I can do this with normal shortcuts. My problem is to trigger just a shortcut "Alt". The problem is that this cannot be handled as a normal shortcut because it cannot react to key press event (at that moment you do not know whether any more keys will be pressed to form a shortcut like Alt+Left). So it needs to react to key  release event. But then it gets triggered when a shortcut like Alt+Left is relased.

Comment: Your code (UPDATE: minimal example ) is working very well ! If I push "Alt+Left" I will see "Trigered!"

Comment: Yeah... But the problem is with "Alt" which should open the menu.

Comment: I've changed my code. Code is working correct - when I push the "Alt" method showMenu(); are called

Comment: Well... but it shows the menu even if I press Alt+Left, which is what I do not want.

Comment: You can implement any logic, for example, the implementation above (I've changed the code and now If you press Alt+Left menu will not appear)